# not receive notification on my device , just in console

Tags: swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I do below steps to receive notifications on my device :

1. activate push notification in xcode/capability .
2. activate notification on my developer account and also add .p12 file to Firebase console .

I get notification in xcode console but nothing will show on my device . 
here is my code :

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import Vox
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

    var responseData : String!


    func registerForPushNotifications() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current() 
            .requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { 
                granted, error in
                print("Permission granted: \(granted)") 
        }
    }

    func getNotificationSettings() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in
            print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
            guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
        Messaging.messaging()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
                .requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
                    [weak self] granted, error in

                    print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
                    guard granted else { return }
                    self?.getNotificationSettings()
            }
        }
        else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        registerForPushNotifications()

        return true
    }

//for receive group messaging
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegister notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {

        Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: responseData)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {

        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        print(userInfo)
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

         Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        print(userInfo)
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data
        ) {
        let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data in String(format: "%02.2hhx", data) }
        let token = tokenParts.joined()
        print("Device Token: \(token)")
    }
}
extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
    }
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }
}

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
         Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        print(userInfo)
        completionHandler([.alert])
    }


    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

what is wrong with my code?!?

Comment: What iOS version are you trying this with? Also it would be great if you share your payload.

Comment: Also while I do know that you said you're receiving it in the console, but are you sure, firebase works end to end in your country. I'm not sure how related [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37373532/why-is-firebase-based-app-not-working-in-iran) is to you

Comment: @Honey ios 12.2 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how you send APNs token in firebase
You can recheck guide step by step
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client
If i have problem, usually i make empty project and setup (any lib) this in clean
In your case i don't see how you send device token (APNs) to firebase
You **have function**

```
func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data
        ) {
        let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data in String(format: "%02.2hhx", data) }
        let token = tokenParts.joined()
        print("Device Token: \(token)")
    }
```

In guide i see this example, you don't send token like this

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
                 didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
  Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
}
```

Maybe you have other problems.
For example if your application in foreground, for default behavior don't showing any alert or banner.